# Second click on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, toggle, flip

I was wondering what's the easier way to change the .mouseleave for a .click in this Flip Effect:

It's doesnt work just by changing it, I've read about using .toggle but not sure how.

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('flipped');
        });
        return false;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/GDdtS/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you binding events in a click handler to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As easy as:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $('.card', this).toggleClass('flipped');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/GDdtS/2252/

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could also use the hover event just as well:

```
$('.flip').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('.card').removeClass('flipped');
    }
);
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/2253/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery's [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```